# Problem with TeXnicCenter and MikTeX

Tags: miktex, texniccenter

I had installed MiKTeX 2.7 and TeXnicCenter 1 Stable RC1. I had made my Ph.D. thesis files in that but due to an accident my hard drive is crashed and I have to make my thesis again.

I am trying to install MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXnicCenter 2 Alpha 2. It is installed but when I am running my LaTeX file it is showing error that the source file is more than five years old.

Please tell me what to do?

Comment: Did you install MiKTeX 2.9 & TeXnicCenter 2 Alpha 2 on a completely new system? Or does it have an existing TeX distribution on it?

Comment: As a novice, it may be difficult to read the error in TeXnicCenter. Being a novice, i use TeXnicCenter for typesetting and winshell to read the error. It may be helpful for you to install [WinShell](http://www.winshell.org/modules/ws_download/) and identify the error and later work with TeXnicCenter

Comment: Googling [latex 5 years](https://www.google.com/search?q=latex+5+years) indicates that you're probably not really using MiKTeX 2.9. There's probably a very old version already installed on the system. Either uninstall it and rerun the TeXnicCenter build wizard, or rerun the build wizard and point it at the newer MiKTeX files.

Comment: @Anil Thank you for the advice, I converted your answer to a comment, since it's more like a comment but not a solution.

Answer (score 4):

All basic macros for LaTeX is contained with [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx). There is a version-control component (originally from [`ltvers.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/ltvers.dtx)) which checks whether your existing `latex.ltx` is too old:

```
%%% From File: ltvers.dtx
\def\fmtname{LaTeX2e}
\edef\fmtversion{2011/06/27}
\iffalse
\def\reserved@a#1/#2/#3\@nil{%
  \count@\year
  \advance\count@-#1\relax
  \multiply\count@ by 12\relax
  \advance\count@\month
  \advance\count@-#2\relax}
\expandafter\reserved@a\fmtversion\@nil
\ifnum\count@>65
  \typeout{^^J%
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!^^J%
!  You are attempting to make a LaTeX format from a source file^^J%
!  That is more than five years old.^^J%
!^^J%
!  If you enter <return> to scroll past this message then the format^^J%
!  will be built, but please consider obtaining newer source files^^J%
!  before continuing to build LaTeX.^^J%
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!^^J%
}
   \errhelp{To avoid this error message, obtain new LaTeX sources.}
   \errmessage{LaTeX source files more than 5 years old!}
\fi
```

It checks whether `\fmtversion` is older than 65 months. If it is, then it prints the message you report, otherwise it continues without problem.

You either didn't install the latest version of MiKTeX 2.9 properly, or there's another distribution interfering with it. Re-install it correctly to obtain an up-to-date version.

Alternatively, if this does not work (for whatever reason), you can edit `latex.ltx`<sup>*</sup> and modify the condition `\ifnum\count@>65` to (say) `\ifnum\count@>100`. However, it's best to properly install and update your distribution.

<sup>*</sup> Perhaps located in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base`.